# How to select a row inside a datagridview cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Dear users: I have a datagridview that im using in a windows form with c sharp, this datagridview has columns as follows:

- name
- price
- detail

I have buttons that will set values for each of this cells, a row can contain only one name and price, but several detail lines, for wich purpose ive separated each entry with a environmental.newline, in case the entry is for details.

[image]

Ok so i hope u get the idea, now the real interesting part is i want the user to be able to clic and select one of this subrows that are inside the datagriview row for this item. also this datagrid is not binded to any table. Can this be done? thank u all in advanced

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I have edited your question. If you're using winforms please tag your question `[winforms]`. And include code samples of whatever you're having problems with.

Comment: Ok thx, ill be careful to do so next time :)

Answer (score 2):

Posting this answer because the OP requested it.

This is how you would do that in WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.ListBoxInCell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ListBoxInCell" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Content="Show Selected Detail" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                Click="ShowDetail"/>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Producto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Product}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Detalle">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetail}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class ListBoxInCell : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public ListBoxInCell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = ViewModel = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void ShowDetail(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ViewModel.SelectedItem.SelectedDetail);
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Data> Items { get; set; }

    public Data SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        //Sample Data
        Items = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => new Data
            {
                Product = "Product" + x.ToString(),
                Details = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
                                    .Select(d => "Detail" + x.ToString() + "-" + d.ToString())
                                    .ToList()
            }).ToList();
        SelectedItem = Items.First();
    }
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Product { get; set; }

    public List<string> Details { get; set; } 

    public string SelectedDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

- MVVM, which means data is separate from UI and UI is separate from data.
- No "owner draw", no "P/Invoke" (whatever that means), and no horrible procedural hacks. Only beautiful XAML and DataBinding.
- The selection of each `ListBox` inside each row is indiviual, you may want to keep only 1 selected Item by setting all the others to `null` with a simple LINQ query and an iteration.
- click on the button to see the currently selected Detail for the currently selected Row in the ListView.
- WPF Rocks, copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.
- Forget winforms. It's useless. It doesn't support any level of customization and requires a lot of horrible hacks for everything. It doesn't support (real) DataBinding and forces you into a boring procedural approach.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView don't supports sub-rows in a row. So, my advice is that you should use two DataGridViews:

- One contains list of Names and Prices.
- Another one display list of Detail lines that belong to current selected row in the first DataGridView.

Comment: i would prety much like to se that in wpf, if u could show me some code id apreciate it =D