# How do I present the contents of my object in DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Here is my code:

```
void Main() {
    List<Restaurant> restaurants = new List<Restaurant>();
}

class Restaurant {
    public int Id;
    public List<Complaint> Complaints = new List<Complaints>();
}

class Complaint {
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public int Age;
    public DateTime ComplaintDate;
}
```

I'd like to present the data contained in RestaurantData, an object of class Restaurant, in the DataGridView control.  First I'd like to show the Restaurant's ID, followed by the number of Complaints against the restaurant so that it looks something like this (where the ID is in column A, and the Name is in Column B, and so forth):

- ID    Name   Address   Age   Date
- Name   Address   Age   Date
- Name   Address   Age   Date

My past usage of DataGridView has been limited to dataGridView1.DataSource = (some array).  However, the information I want to present this time is clearly not an array so I'm stuck.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18926575/643085)?

Comment: I assume that this is WinForms because your previous question was Winforms correct?

Comment: That answer should have it.  Sorry it took a bit, I got pulled away mid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cull the columns to your own list, something like this works:

```
private void AddColumns()
{
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ageColumn =
        new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    ageColumn.Name = "Age";
    ageColumn.DataPropertyName = "Age";
    ageColumn.ReadOnly = true;

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nameColumn =
        new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    nameColumn.Name = "Name";
    nameColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
    nameColumn.ReadOnly = true;

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn addressColumn =
        new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    addressColumn.Name = "Address";
    addressColumn.DataPropertyName = "Address";
    addressColumn.ReadOnly = true;

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dateColumn =
        new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    addressColumn.Name = "Date";
    addressColumn.DataPropertyName = "Date";
    addressColumn.ReadOnly = true;

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(ageColumn);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(addressColumn);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dateColumn);

    var ds = (from r in restaurants
              from c in r.Complaints
              select new {Id = r.Id, Address =c.Address, Age = c.Age, Name = c.Name, Date = c.ComplaintDate}
             ).ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
}
```

If you just want to autogenerate the columns try this:

```
private void AddColumns()
{
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

    var ds = (from r in restaurants
              from c in r.Complaints
              select new {Id = r.Id, Address =c.Address, Age = c.Age, Name = c.Name, Date = c.ComplaintDate}
             ).ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
}
```

Comment: How does this resolve the Master-Detail (Nested Grid) issue the OP is talking about?

Comment: @HighCore I was working on that when i got pulled away.  The updated answer should have it.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the OP wants. I guess we will have to ask for clarification. BTW, [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/WhatsNew2012v1/i/xpf-grid-master-detail-table-views.png) is what I mean when I say "Master / detail"

Comment: OIC.. Hrm... Need more clarification for sure.

Comment: Sorry guys, I had another task that took me away from this question.  Do appreciate the responses.  Need some time to process and understand what paqogomez wrote.

Comment: @paqogomez "restaurants" is highlighted by the compiler and says "could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.restaurants'. 'SelectMany' not found.  Also, I don't need the nested grid that HighCore mentions.  I just want a table that displays everything at once without having the user to double click to expand layers (scrolling down is perfectly fine).

Comment: Ok, then what I have will do it.  Make sure you are `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @paqogomez Quick question.  How do I make it so that the restaurant name only shows up ONCE, instead of in every single row that represents a complaint?

Comment: To give you an idea of what I mean, please look in my above example where "ID" only shows up once (and the complaints for the restaurants follow).  From what I can tell the code currently puts ID in every row.

Comment: @phan I'm afraid that while the question is quick, the answer is not. I would suggest that you could loop through the data and build another list with null's or empty strings where you need them.  I have tried a lot of permutations to make this happen, even [posted an SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108323/select-null-in-a-linq-query-if-the-value-is-in-a-previous-record/19108781?noredirect=1#comment28254729_19108781) but have not been able to make anything work that does this. Essentially, you are using a data source for a report viewer.  Best to find a report viewer IMO.

Comment: To be clear, looping should work, a linq answer.. probably not.

Comment: @paqogomez Wow, thanks so much for the response. I appreciate it.  I read that other SO question and appreciate what you're saying.  I will try to process that one too, and see if it works for me.

Comment: FWIW, I didnt get to try the solution w/ the `Skip()` in it, but it is the closest to what we want.  Good luck! :)

Comment: No worries, I'm just happy that I have something to try/experiment.  Plus, the way you asked the question was 1000 times better than I could have written it.  Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks :) go vote up the question.. i thought more people would like it :)