# Select null in a linq query if the value is in a previous record

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following query:

```
var ds = (from t1 in list1
          from t2 in list2
          select new {t1.Name, t2.Name}
         ).ToList();
```

This returns something like: (rough representation)

```
Name1, InnerName1
Name1, InnerName2
Name2, InnerName1
Name2, InnerName2
```

What I would like to get is:

```
Name1, InnerName1
Null, InnerName2
Name2, InnerName1
Null, InnerName2.
```

Meaning, **if I have already t1.Name in the list, I'd like null or empty string on the rest of t1's results**.

I already know that I could loop through the results, but I'm using this as a datasource and would like to do something set based.

Is there a way to accomplish this in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your using Linq-to-Objects, you could do something like this:

```
string previous = null;
var results = 
    (from t1 in list1
     from t2 in list2
     select new {
         Name1 = (previous == t1.Name) ? null : (previous = t1.Name), 
         Name2 = t2.Name 
     })
    .ToList();
```

But that relies on side effects and isn't particularly elegant. You might prefer something like this:

```
var result = 
    (from t1 in list1
     select 
       list2.Take(1)
         .Select(t2 => new { Name1 = t1.Name,  Name2 = t2.Name })
         .Concat(list2.Skip(1)
           .Select(t2 => new { Name1 = (string)null, Name2 = t2.Name }))
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The `Concat` answer seems to be a good one, and I am still working on getting it implemented.  I dont know however how you are excluding the first row in the concatenation that `First()` took at the first of the query.

Comment: @paqogomez Oops, I meant to include a `.Skip(1)`; see my updated answer.

Comment: In the first example I think the true/false condition needs to be switched so that null comes first (if the condition evaluates to true).

Comment: Also, with the first example, when I set a datagrid.datasource = result I only see Name2, and not Name1.  Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: @phan Yes, I think you're right about reversing the arguments in the conditional expression, but I can't think of any reason why you wouldn't see both columns.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need the cross join here.
Try  this.

```
//will get null values for both
    var ds = (from t1 in list1
              join t2 in list2 into t3
              from objt3 in t3.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new {t1.Name, objt3.Name}
             ).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

```
//will get null values for second list
    var ds = (from t1 in list1
              join t2 in list2 into t3
              from objt3 in t3.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where t1 != null
              select new {t1.Name, objt3.Name}
             ).ToList();
```

**Updated:**

```
//will get null values for second list
    var ds = (from t1 in list1
              where t1 != null
              join t2 in list2 into t3
              from objt3 in t3.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new {t1.Name, objt3.Name}
             ).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not getting the second query to compile, though i cant see anything wrong with it.  The `into` in the second one is giving me an error of `Unexpected Token`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following, which basically simulates the loop that you are trying to avoid by using `Aggregate`. Unfortunately, it cannot use an anonymous class anymore, since we need to use `Enumerable.Empty<Data>()` to start the aggregation:

```
class Data { public string Name; public string Inner; };

// Test data
var data = new Data[] 
{
    new Data {Name = "Name1", Inner = "InnerName1"},
    new Data {Name = "Name1", Inner = "InnerName2"},
    new Data {Name = "Name2", Inner = "InnerName1"},
    new Data {Name = "Name2", Inner = "InnerName2"}
};

// remove duplicate Names
var filtered = data.Aggregate(
    Enumerable.Empty<Data>(),
    (list, newitem) => list.Concat(new Data[] {new Data {
        Name = (list.Any() && list.Last().Name == newitem.Name)
                ? null : newitem.Name,
        Inner = newitem.Inner
    }}));
```

Comment: This is probably a simple miscommunication in my post, but I worked through this answer and I realized that this query creates nested results.  A hierarchy.  However, I already have the nested results, I am trying to flatten them.  Like a report view might look.  Does that make sense?  Perhaps I have missed something?

Comment: @paqogomez: It should not create nested results: `filtered` is simply an `IEnumerable<Data>`. When I run `foreach (Data d in filtered) { Console.WriteLine(d.Name + ", " + d.Inner); }`, I get exactly the result that you requested in your question.

Comment: The confusion might come in because I have my data in two lists, where you have 1 data class.  So, perhaps I've implemented poorly

Answer (score 1):

Not far from what p.s.w.g. came up with, this doesn't use the query syntax. It avoids `.First()` and uses `Zip`.

```
var listResult = list1.SelectMany(x => (new[] { x, })
  .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((string)null, int.MaxValue))
  .Zip(list2, (y, z) => new { Name1 = y, Name2 = z, }));
```

Answer (score 1):

To treat the first item in the sequence differently you can just use the overload of `Select` that pass in an index, which we can compare to zero.

That overload isn't accessible in query syntax, and the query looks a bit nicer with all method syntax rather than mixing and matching.

```
var query = list1.SelectMany(t1 => list2.Select((t2, i) => new
{
    Name1 = i == 0 ? t1.Name : null,
    Name2 = t2.Name
}));
```

Comment: Oh my.. I'd forgotten that little trick.  That might be exactly what I need.  I'll test it out.