# Building a model for treeListView in objectListView

Tags: c#, .net, objectlistview

I have been trying to build a model for treeListView but cannot seem to get the right structure for my requirements. I am quite new to objectListView and have looked through the samples and cookbook but not sure how build my model correctly. Here is simplified version of my model:

I have a parent lets call it "A".

There are 2 columns (Name, Value). "A" would be the Name of the parent and Value can be set to "1".

"A" has two children which do not have a Name but both carry a Value, "2" for the 1st child and "3" for the second child. The tree stops at this point.

So we have a structure like so:

```
Name     Value

A        1

         2

         3
```

Here is the code to setup the treeListView:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeListViewTest1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x) 
            { 
                return true; 
            };
            this.treeListView1.ChildrenGetter = delegate(object x) 
            {
                Contract contract = x as Contract;
                return contrat.Children;
            };

            column1.AspectGetter = delegate(object x)
            {
                if(x is Contract)
                {
                    return ((Contract)x).Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    return " ";
                }
            };

            column2.AspectGetter = delegate(object x)
            {
                if(x is Contract)
                {
                    return ((Contract)x).Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Double d = (Double)x;
                    return d.ToString();
                }
            };

            this.treeListView1.AddObject(new Contract("A", 1));

        }

        private void treeListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Contract
    {
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public Double Value { get; set; }
        public List<Double> Children {get; set;}

        public Contract(string name, Double value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
            Children = new List<Double>();
            Children.Add(2);
            Children.Add(3);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I stop the Children from having an expansion symbol (+) since they cannot be expanded because they are not parents?

Comment: Did you forget to set an AspectName or install an AspectGetter for the columns?

Comment: Also, you should explain what you want to achieve exactly. Note that the child object can be of a different type that the parent. It seems somewhat irritating that you want to display Name and Value for the parent while you only use Value for the Children. Maybe a separate Child object would fit your needs.

Comment: What is AspectName and AspectGetter?

Comment: I didn't realise the child can be different from the parent. How would i construct that. I am a little confused as to how you can have a different parent and child.

Comment: Ok I am getting a little closer to what I want:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is AspectName and AspectGetter?
>   You have to tell the Columns, where to get the data from. You can either set the AspectName property of a column to the name of the model objects property OR you can use an AspectGetter delegate that gives you complete control about what to put in the column.

**AspectName example**

You can set the aspect name from within the VS designer or set it manually like this:

```
// this would tell the column to get the content from the property named "Name"
olvColumn1.AspectName = "Name";
```

**AspectGetter example**

We attach an anonymous method in this example, you could also use a method name with matching signature.

```
// this lets you handle the model object directly
olvColumn1.AspectGetter = delegate(object rowObject) {
    // check if that is the expected model type
    if (rowObject is MyObject) {
        // just return the value of "Name" in this simple case
        return ((MyObject)rowObject).Name;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
};
```

> I didn't realise the child can be different from the parent. How would i construct that. I am a little confused as to how you can have a different parent and child.

Just return any kind of List in the ChildrenGetter. Using the AspectName, the ObjectListView just tries to find a property with the given name. Using the Aspectgetter, you handle the contents manually anyway and can check the type of the model from the row.

> How do I stop the Children from having an expansion symbol (+) since they cannot be expanded because they are not parents?

You have to check if the object actually has any children. Only return `true` in the CanExpandGetter if thats the case. Example:

```
this.treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x) { 
    if (rowObject is MyObject) {
        return (((MyObject)x).Children.Count > 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Perfect see my updated code above. I have the question there about how to stop the children having an expandable option (+)? Since this leads to an error. Also I used your answer in another post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188245/objectlistview-how-to-show-child-list